# Gradient on transparent.png only appears in IE 8.0.7061

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, background-image, transparent

Hi Ladies and Gentleman,

I've got a really strange one here I think. Basically I've applied a background color of to a Panel for some content boxes that on IE 8.0.7061 look like they have a gradient on them. Issue below.

[image: Picture of issue]

The client then came back to me complaining that they needed this for IE8 so I added a simple 1x1 transparent.png with the same opacity percentage I used in the Alpha channel in the RGBA code.

This is what I ended up with;

```
   background: url(../img/transparent.png) repeat;
   background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
```

Now, the above code works in every other browser variation. I just can't understand what could be going wrong. I've run a VM with the same Win version and IE version and I can't replicate it but I can't explain to the client why I can't fix it..Here's what it looks like in every other Browser and IE Version 8(6.0) and IE9+

[image: Intended Result]

Comment: [rgba colors aren't supported in IE8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-colors)

Comment: Yes. I know. That's why I have the fall back image..